# Convert servlet to a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

I have a servlet to a webservice in java,

I have a servlet that process user information ,(registeration) and return a result as a string , how do I use that servlet as webservice to be called and do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Look at JAX-WS that is a Java specification for webservices, making a POJO service available as a Webservice Soap Endpoint.
http://jax-ws.java.net/

You may need to move your code from your servlet to a POJO class.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods depending on your need. 
I found the WebService Axix User guide quite useful here -> http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html

It contains description on how to use the Java2WSDL tool which ultimately allows you to publish your final webservice. http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Java2WSDLBuildingWSDLFromJava